# Mongoose filter subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql, aggregation-framework

Having schema like:

```
     {
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "views": [
    {
      "name": "AAA",
      "permissions": ['PERM_1','PERM_2']
    },
    {
      "name": "BBB",
      "permissions": ['PERM_2']
    },
    {
      "name": "CCC",
      "permissions": ['PERM_3']
    }]
}
```

I would like to get result with views that contains 'PERM_1' and 'PERM_3' like this:

```
{
 "_id": ObjectId("..."),
 "views": [
        {
  "name": "AAA",
  "permissions": ['PERM_1','PERM_2']
 },
 {
   "name": "CCC",
   "permissions": ['PERM_3']
 }]
}
```

However, I am not really successful in getting the result I wanted. Here is my query:

```
Schema.aggregate([
{
    $project: {
        views: {
            $filter: {
                input: '$views.permissions',
                as: 'perm',
                cond: {
                    ????? // return only PERM_1 and PERM_3
                }
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content of condition can be:

```
$filter: {
  input: '$views',
  as: 'perm',
  cond: {
    cond: {
          $gt: [
            {
              $size: {
                $setIntersection: ['$$perm.permissions',['PERM_1','PERM_2']],
              },
            },
            0,
          ],
        },
  }
}
```

---

You can check mongo technical documentation for more details

- [Aggregation setIntersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/)